# How to get PhpStorm to understand different SQL dialects in HEREDOC in the same project

Tags: mysql, sql-server, phpstorm, syntax-highlighting, heredoc

My PHP 7.3 application connects to MS SQL Server or MariaDB, depending on being run under Windows or Linux.

For my queries, I sometimes write queries **in SQL Server syntax** and sometimes **in MySQL syntax**. For code validation etc. I use [PhpStorm's language injection via HEREDOC](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-language-injections.html#inject-language-nowdoc-heredoc)

Of course, only the dialect that is configured in the project, is validated correctly.

Example:

```
switch ($dt_type) {
    case 'MSSQL':
        $sql_string = <<<SQL
            [MSSQL query here]
        SQL;
    case 'MYSQL':
    case 'MSSQL':
        $sql_string = <<<SQL
            [MYSQL query here]
        SQL;
}
```

I configured the MSSQL dialect in my project, so PhpStorm (correctly, expectedly) marks my MySQL queries as invalid and quirks the syntax highlighting.

Is there a way to tell PhpStorm, that a specific string should be validated with a different SQL dialect, for example by declaring it in a comment just before that string declaration? I tried the `@lang` annotation, and language injection comments.. without any success.

I am aware it might not be possible, but maybe someone knows a trick?

Comment: I feel that this question is off-topic here (or maybe not); anyways star-marked as I would also like to know the answer. If you figure out the answer yourself; do post it here :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`SQL` is used to apply the **current** SQL Dialect for that file *(in case if you do not know: you can configure the IDE to have different dialects on per file/folder basis)*.

[image]

---

To have two dialects **in the same file**:

1. Do not use `SQL` as an identifier if you will be changing it across the project (as it will use *current* SQL Dialect for that file).

   *I mean: you can use it, not an issue; but do not get lost/confused if you change the dialect later for that folder/file or for the whole project.*
2. Create and use more specific identifiers instead that will instruct the IDE to use a specific dialect there.

It's easy: just clone and adjust a bit a Language Injection rule for the bundled `SQL` identifier:

1. `Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Language Injections`
2. Clone existing rule for `<<<SQL` and adjust as needed (or create new one from scratch using the right type)

[image]

As you may see from this example, string for PostgreSQL complains on syntax (there is no DB attached to the project, hence unknown `table` table):

[image]

---

In-place language injection via `@lang` also works. NOTE that the injection must be placed just before the string content, not before the variable etc.

```
$sql1 = /** @lang MySQL */'SELECT * FROM `table`';
$sql2 = /** @lang PostgreSQL */'SELECT * FROM `table`';
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks for the elaborate answer! I'll check it the custom language injection, really cool :-)

Comment: One question: can I checkin this custom setting somehow so my custom lang injector will be available for other developers with PhpStorm?

Comment: Language Injection rules can be IDE wide and project specific. Project specific entries are saved in `PROJECT/.idea` folder (`IntelliLang.xml` file AFAIK) which  can be shared via VCS/easily copied manually. IDE wides ones -- import/export buttons ARE available for that Settings screen + config file can also be copy-pasted manually between computers.